# How can I submit snowpark application in production

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, spark-submit

How can I submit snowpark application in production. I have written snow snowpark code and I am unable to find resources on how to submit the code in production.

I am getting this error when I run snowpark application

```
Here is the error when I run as a java jarException in thread "main" net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: User Error Report:
Java Stack Trace:
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: us.company.snowpark.app.SnowparkAppDriver$
    at function_handler_0//com.snowflake.snowpark.internal.JavaUtils$.doDeserializeAndCloseInputStream(JavaUtils.scala:351)
    at function_handler_0//com.snowflake.snowpark.internal.JavaUtils$.deserialize(JavaUtils.scala:335)
    at function_handler_0//com.snowflake.snowpark.internal.JavaUtils.deserialize(JavaUtils.scala)
    at function_handler_0//SnowUDF.<init>(InlineCode.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: us.zoom.snowpark.app.SnowparkAppDriver$
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:745)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1965)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1851)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1814)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1639)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2434)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2328)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2166)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1668)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:482)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:440)
    at function_handler_0//com.snowflake.snowpark.internal.JavaUtils$.doDeserializeAndCloseInputStream(JavaUtils.scala:348)
    ... 3 more
 in function SNOWPARK_TEMP_FUNCTION_225OXEHNSNMLXN1 with handler SnowUDF.compute
```

Comment: What do you mean by submit code in production? Snowpark is a client side library, so can you explain a bit more exactly what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I have created a snowpark application to transform data present in snowflake and load it back to snowflake, I would like to schedule this app to run daily. How can I do that. If it is spark job we can run it with spark submit command and schedule it in any tool

Comment: A Snowpark application is just a standalone app. To run it based on a schedule you can probably use the OS scheduler, like crontab in Linux.

Comment: Do we need to package this snowpark application into a jar to run with OS scheduler? @Sergiu

Comment: Yes, most probably you need to generate a jar and as long as you can run the as a normal Java/Scala app then you can schedule it via OS scheduler as well.

Comment: I am getting the above error in description when I run it as a java jar. WIthout packaging as java jar and running in IntelliJ works fine, but when I run it as java jar throws above error

Answer (score 0):

Exporting the application to a java jar, then uploading the java jar to the snowflake stage solved the problem. I am now able to run the application from the command line.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).